# How to change the value in asp Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working on a legacy project where i got a line like this .

```
string xslpath = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("flpath")).Text;
```

Now from the above line , i am getting the value like ..

> \RL-DEV-02\Page\9100864297\Page_Agent_2102016 81828 AM.htm

Now as per my requirement i need to change the **\RL-DEV-02** to **\RL-DEV-05** but i am not able to find out where the value has been fixed.

Please help me to get it done.

Comment: Cant you use `Replace()`?

Comment: @Hemal I got it ..Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Label control value would be set in HTML (.ascx) or may be in code behind or through client side script (jQuery). You need to find out in the source code. Although you can change the value any where like you are getting it.

```
((Label)e.Item.FindControl("flpath")).Text = "New Value";
```

Comment: Thanks for you help , it moved me but i got another issue where the line `LinkButton lnkevent = (LinkButton)(e.Item.FindControl("flpath"));` is giving this exception `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.`, I dont know what is it or how to resolve it..

Comment: flpath is probably label but you are casting it to LinkButton, if it is Label then change the statement to, Label lnkevent = (Label)(e.Item.FindControl("flpath"));

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
string xslpath = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("flpath")).Text;
string newstring=xslpath.Replace("RL-DEV-02","RL-DEV-05");
```